# Relating the number of solutions to a CSP to the size of the domain and the width of its constraint hypergraph

Tags: artificial-intelligence, constraint-satisfaction

Let $P$ be a constraint satisfaction problem with $n$ variables, each with the same finite
domain $D$, and with $m$ > 0 constraints, where each constraint is an $AllDifferent$ constraint
of arity $k$, for some fixed $k ≥ 2$

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following statements:

- If $|D|$ is equal to the treewidth of the constraint hypergraph of $P$, then $P$ has no
  solutions.
- If $|D|$ is greater than the treewidth of the constraint hypergraph of $P$, then $P$ has at least one solution.

I can't think of any concrete counter examples/proofs for either of these because a node can have several constraints encoded in it.